# Is this use of threadvar threadsafe?

Tags: string, delphi, thread-safety

I've got a singleton that can be called by multiple threads.
I do some lookup of data pretty often and I what to cache the data so that I don't have to repeat the same lookup again and again.

I'd like to do something akin to using static local variables, but in a thread-safe way. I suspect the code below is watertight. Is this correct?

```
type
  TPrevious = record
  public
    Fontname: string;
    FontSize: integer;
    Canvas: pointer;
    Width: integer;
  end;

threadvar Previous: TPrevious;

function TEditorOptions.GetEditorFontWidth(const Canvas: TCanvas): integer;
var
  Font: TFont;
//var  //static vars            <<-- static var != threadsafe
//  PreviousFontName: string = '';
//  PreviousFontSize: integer = 0;
//  PreviousCanvas: pointer = nil;
//  PreviousWidth: integer = 0;
begin
  {1: I'm assuming a managed threadvar is always initialized to Default(T)}
  if (Previous.Fontname <> '') then begin
      //Cache the values, so we don't recalculate all the time.
      //Caching is per thread, but that's fine.
    if (SameText(Previous.FontName, FFontName)) and (Previous.FontSize = FFontSize)
       and (pointer(Canvas) = Previous.Canvas) then Exit(Previous.Width);
  end;
  Previous.Canvas := pointer(Canvas);
  Previous.FontName := FFontName;
  Previous.FontSize := FFontSize;
  Result:= SomeCalculation(Canvas, FFontName, FFontSize);
  ....
    Previous.Width:= Result;
  ....
end;
```

I have 2 questions:

A: Am I correct in assuming that managed threadvars like the string `FontName` are always initialized to `Default(T)` (i.e. `''`)

B: Is this code fully threadsafe/ re-entrant?

Comment: The VCL is **not** thread-safe. So using a TCanvas will never be thread-safe, even if the variable storing the instance is thread-safe. ;)

Comment: @ArnaudBouchez, I managed to fix that by using an alternative method that does not use a Canvas, This also fixes the problem with the Threadvar not cleaning up after itself and thus not releasing the string.

Comment: Thanks all for a very enlightening discussion. I did not know that threadvars do not clean up after themselves, which will quickly lead to resource leaks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Any `threadvar` instance is filled with zero, so your `string` variable is properly initialized.
2. Sadly, `threadvar` do not handle the memory of their managed type... 
   As a result, you need to release each `string` inside your `Previous` variable.
3. In practice, I do not store managed types in threadvar, but use another pattern (like injection at constructor level).
4. Small performance hit: access to each `Previous.xxxxx` member has a performance cost: you may rather fill a local variable pointer with `@Previous`, then use this pointer to access the fields (or use `with Previous do` - but this syntax may be confusing).

Answer (score 3):

All thread vars, managed or not, are zero initialized. Note though that they are not finalised when the thread terminates so you need to take charge of that.

There are no data races because you use a thread var. I'm not sure what you mean when you ask about re-entrancy. Nothing in the code suggests re-entrant execution.

Answer (score 2):

You already have suitable answers to your question A, so I'm only going to focus on "Is this use of threadvar threadsafe?". I'll start by considering the thread safety of `threadvar` first. Then I'll call out a couple of observations about the code in your question.

Nothing in the code you have presented raises any alarm bells. However, hopefully the information I have provided will help you confidently make your own assessment based on the rest of your code.

---

Strictly speaking `threadvar` is ***NOT*** thread-safe. The only thing that threadvars provide is a version of the variable local to each thread. The fact that each thread has its own copy can lead to a *false-logic* over simplification: i.e. assuming that the data is thread-safe.

The important point of *thread-local variables* is that each thread has its own copy of the data, and therefore *should not need any of the typical thread-safety mechanisms*.

***However*** It's still possible to *share data* via thread-variables.

- Object variables in different threads could reference shared objects.
- String variables could reference shared strings<sup>A</sup>.
- Pointer variables could reference the same memory location<sup>B</sup>.
- Even records and primitive type thread-variables can be shared by taking the address `@` of one thread's variable and that finding its way to another thread.

Given the above, A and require further consideration because your record has a string and a Pointer.

As you well know. Delphi's handling of long strings means the string variable's data could very well be shared across multiple threads. Fortunately each variable (including each threadvar instance) will hold its own refcount. Given Delphi's COW and interlocked access to refcount, you can rest assured that the string will be safe... *Assuming of course you don't have any dodgy code that bypasses the ref-counting to manipulate the string.*

The `Canvas: Pointer` is a little less clear though. I suspect you might only be holding it for the pointer itself. But if you actually intend using a shared canvas you're likely to experience difficulties.

---

## Conclusion

- Thread-variables are not actually "thread-safe". But usually they don't need to be, because by intent threadvars usually don't share data.
- However, threadvars *can be* used in such a way that data is shared. So you still need to pay attention to this possibility.
- Finally, the code presented looks safe. But your final answer may depend on whether `Canvas` is shared what's happening inside `SomeCalculation`.

---

#### As an aside

You explained your intent to cache some lookup data. There is a serious alternative worth considering. If your shared/cached data resides in an *immutable* object, then any number of threads can safely read the data concurrently. ***NB*** You do need to guarantee that no other threads can modify the data concurrently though.

Comment: To avoid confusion, last time I checked, Delphi *string variables are not thread-safe*. Locked ref-counting makes them thread-safe when all threads do only read operations, but not when you perform some writes to the string. In a nutshell, assignment to the same string variable is not thread-safe: you have to protect the variable slot (e.g. using a mutex). In the case of the threadvar, each thread will have its own slot, so it will be threadsafe. But not for regular variables.

Comment: @ArnaudBouchez You're correct that strings aren't automatically thread-safe; and one shouldn't assume they are. However writes are fine provided each thread that has access to the string has its own refCount. Then COW kicks in: the string can be safely copied bc that's a read operation; the refCount is safely decreased with Interlock; and the copied string can be safely modified bc only 1 thread is looking at the copy at until it is shared again.  ***The thing to watch out for is***: 2 threads share an object or record that contains a string (or normal global string)... _(cont.)_

Comment: a string shared in the above manner might still have `refCount = 1` even though multiple threads are looking at the string. This string would be subject to typical multi-threaded race conditions. In addition there would be a risk of some trickier problems if multiple threads attempt certain concurrent operations: e.g. T1 refCount reduced to 0 => string destroyed at same time T2 refCount is increased. Or T1 reallocs string at same time T2 is reading.

Comment: Nevertheless: COW is safe with multiple threads ***if and only if*** each thread "looking at" a shared string contributes at least 1 counter to the `refCount`.

Comment: I'm afraid you may miss some details, or I didn't understand  your wording. RefCount increment/decrement by itself is ensured to be atomic, since it uses some dedicated asm instructions for that. The main problem is not about RefCount atomicity, but when strings are copied to be modified during the COW process.

Comment: @ArnaudBouchez No, I've covered all the salient points. I'm not sure what's tripping you up. Unfortunately it's not feasible to give a more detailed explanation in comments. If you're genuinely interested in a such an explanation, I can possibly put the time in to post a self-answer this weekend?

Comment: No need to argue/debate/expand. You may have covered all the points, my comment is just about how confusing it may be to understand how COW works in multi-threading, and that no answer may be clear enough in practice...

Comment: @Arnaud your comment "_The main problem is not about RefCount atomicity, but when strings are copied to be modified during the COW process._" suggests a flawed understanding of exactly what COW can protect; underestimating what it _does_ protect. Yes it can be confusing and there are some gotchas; but if you don't trust COW, you should call `UniqueString` for _every_ string used in threads, avoiding COW altogether! I offered to put in time and effort to explain _(I believe a clear answer **is** possible)._ But you're not interested, so there more time for me to do other things this weekend. ;)